# invisible padding or margin inside iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a page with an iframe. iframe width is 550px and height is 550px.

the iframe loads a html file called test.html
the only thing inside test.html is an img with
a height and width of 550px.

Theoretically now the full image should be visible,
when the whole thing is viewed on  browser/
but the bottom and the right of the img is a cut off by a few pixels.

Whats going on ?

Comment: did you try `iframe body { margin:0 }` the body element has default margin and that is probably what is cutting your image

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle or a piece of code. It will help us to resolve your problem.

Comment: This is why we use [resets](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).